# How do you provide an alternate element for DOCUMENT while bootstrapping an app

Tags: angular

In short, I would like to bootstrap my Angular 4 application within the shadow DOM of a web component.

The out of the box behavior assumes that the component element I am attempting to bootstrap from is present within the browsers document object.  Since I am trying to render a component within a closed shadow DOM, document.querySelector does not find any matching selectors for my component and I see the following error (rooted in `DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement`):

```
error-handler.service.ts:20 Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
at DefaultDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.es5.js:2791)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animations.es5.js:401)
at DebugRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.es5.js:13640)
at createElement (core.es5.js:9173)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12153)
at createRootView (core.es5.js:12082)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13465)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12782)
at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9859)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
```

`DefaultDomRenderer2` doesn't seem to depend on the `DOCUMENT` provider.  Is it even possible to replace the default provider for `DOCUMENT` at run time?  Do I have to write a separate implementation for the renderer?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef)` method of your `AppModule` and configure which components to bootstrap in which elements.

```
@NgModule({...})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
   ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
       ...
   }
}
```